# Extraer valores de una variable pasada como parámetro en PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Dada la siguiente url:

> editar?id=1-2,1-31

Quiero sacar los valores en PHP. Esto entra a la url como un array desde jQuery:

```
var checked = [];
$('.editar').click(function(){
$("input[name='edit[]']:checked").each(function ()
{
  checked.push($(this).val());
  url = "./sedes/editar?id="+checked;
}
```

Esto recoge los checkbox que están seleccionados, mete los valores de los mismos en el array checked y lo envía como parámetro en la url.

El problema es que, como se puede ver en la url, manda un conjunto de x-y y debo separarlo para hacer una consulta en el PHP. El array está recogido en PHP en una variable llamada `$id` pero los valores aparecen como sigue:

```
$id[0]=x
$id[1]=-
$id[2]=y
$id[3]=,
$id[4]=z
$id[5]=-
$id[6]=a
$id[7]=b
$id[8]=,
```

Necesito sacar solo los que contienen las letras. Pensé en separar la cadena de texto por el "-" y sacar el indice anterior y posterior, pero ahora tengo dudas de que me pueda servir, pues los valores vienen de una base de datos y pueden ir desde 1 cifra a 8 cifras antes o despues del guion.

Necesito saber si puedo pasar valores como, por ejemplo, 1-31 (sin que me ponga el 1 en un indice el 3 en otro y el 1 en otro) o si puedo coger este tipo de parámetros de otra manera a través de la url.

Comment: Primero explode por coma y luego explode por -, eso te dejará los pares de valores: $v = explode(",", $_REQUEST[$id]); foreach($v as $i) { $id[] = explode("-", $i); } más o menos...

Comment: Algo mal debo estar haciendo porque esto no chuta: `$id= $_GET['id'];
    // echo $arr[2];
    $v = explode(",", $id);
    foreach($id as $i){ 
        $a = explode(",", $i);
    }
    // echo $v[0];
    foreach($a as $v){ 
        $r = explode("-", $v);
    }
    echo $r[0];`

Comment: Lo he picado en vivo, así que no puedo asegurar su funcionamiento, pero espera un poco que lo pruebo online y te paso el enlace.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Quedo a la espera. A mi me devuelve un error 500, un guión o nada, en función de a que le haga echo.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/58d7fbbcaf47fe9785748d73943b1e632ba65373

Comment: Guay, ahora al menos no muere la web. Pero sigo sin saber como recoger los valores. Soy bastante torpe para estas cosas. Se supone que es un array dentro de un array, no? entrando por  `$out[0][1]` saco el primero valor?

Comment: Si, eso es, aunque tb puedes hacerlo de otra forma si te va mejor, espera que te paso enlace

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e1036b4cb50b9432e8b380925b0894dc8066598

Comment: La idea es buena y, posiblemente la use mas adelante, pero ahora mismo la respuesta de Iñigo Irigoyen me ha sido mas práctica que la complicación de los arrays. No obstante, para otra parte del código si que usare lo que me has explicado.

Comment: Claro! la solución que convenga en cada caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que te estas pasando un array en la url y por eso recibes un array con el `GET['id']`. Necesitas mandar un String y será más fácil:

```
var checked = "";
$('.editar').click(function(){
$("input[name='edit[]']:checked").each(function ()
{
  //Se selecciona el valor de los inputs seleccionados y se añade ",".
  checked += $(this).val()+","; 
  //Se concatena detras de la url. Se puede cambiar lo anterior a ?id para
  //que se ajuste a las necesidades de cada uno
  url = "./sedes/editar?id="+checked;
}
```

Ahora que ya tienes el String en el PHP tratalo de manera más sencilla:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = explode(",", $id);
$dato1 = $id[0]; //x-y
$dato2 = $id[1]; //z-ab
```

Y a partir de aquí lo que necesites.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu interés. Voy a comer, que ando en el curro, cuando suba lo veo y te digo, que me parece muy interesante tu opción, es lo que andaba intentando desde un principio, por eso puse el guión.

Comment: Comprobado. Ahora me devuelve 1-12 con el `$dato2`. No obstante, tuve que poner un +"," detras de `checked += $(this).val()` porque no ponía las comas divisorias en la url. Modifícalo y te la doy por buena. Gracias por tu ayuda.